# C# WPF Button should be displayed as selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, mouseevent

*I'm using C# WPF Application*

I need your help.
If I press on a button it should be selected, but if I now press on another button it should be selected and the other button should not be selected.
It should show where the user is.The button should be selected until another button has been clicked.

But when you go with the mouse over, the normal mouse over effect should come.

```
<Window x:Name="windowsForm" x:Class="Vorschau.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Vorschau"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Vorschaukomponente" Height="514.583" Width="805.208" FontFamily="Century Gothic" WindowStartupLocation="Manual" BorderThickness="0" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" Icon="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Vorschau\Vorschau\img\coordinates.ico" Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="border_res" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3A3A3B" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Border Style="{StaticResource border_res}">
        <Grid>
            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Background="#FFE57E31">
                <Canvas Height="64" Canvas.Top="451" Width="185" Background="#FF2C373F">
                    <Label x:Name="lbCopyright" Content="©  Name 2017" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="29" Width="121" Foreground="#FF1B1D1F"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Height="391" Canvas.Top="60" Width="185" Background="#FF37424A">
                    <Button x:Name="btVorschau" Content="Vorschau" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="185" Height="50" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="16"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Click="Button_Click">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF37424A"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303B43"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="btEinstellung" Content="Einstellung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="185" Height="50" Foreground="LightGray" FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Canvas.Top="50" Click="btEinstellung_Click">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF37424A"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF303B43"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                    </Button>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas Height="60" Canvas.Left="185" Width="618" Background="#FFEEE9ED">
                    <Label x:Name="lbClose" Content="X" Canvas.Left="578" FontSize="20" MouseDoubleClick="lbClose_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbMinimize" Content="-" Canvas.Left="556" FontSize="22" Canvas.Top="-2" MouseDoubleClick="lbMinimize_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                    <Label x:Name="lbWhereIAm" Content="Label" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="15" Width="162" FontSize="20"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas x:Name="canvasContent" Height="455" Canvas.Left="185" Canvas.Top="60" Width="618" Background="#FFD1CFD0">
                    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Height="241" Canvas.Left="93" Canvas.Top="87" Width="440" SelectedIndex="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <TabItem x:Name="tabitem1" Header="TabItem">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF2387FF"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                        <TabItem x:Name="tabitem2" Header="TabItem" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                                <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="138,124,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFF70000"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </TabItem>
                    </TabControl>
                </Canvas>
                <Image x:Name="image" Height="38" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="38" Source="C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Vorschau\Vorschau\img\coordinatesWhite.png"/>
                <Label x:Name="lbLogoname" Content="Vorschaukomponente" Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="10" Width="143" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: Don't use a button. Look for a radio button or a group of toggle buttons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Listbox , to show group of buttons

**Solution 1 :**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Content="{Binding}" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Solution 2**

Use radio button change the template

```
<RadioButton Content="Point" >
    <RadioButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </RadioButton.Template>
</RadioButton>
```